# Jquery not working in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function that not work in another .js file

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
var channelId = '55';
var matn = 'some';
   alert('s');
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'savedata.aspx/insertdata',
          async: false,
          data: "{'channelId':'" + channelId + "','matn':'" + matn + "'}",
          contentType: 'application/json; charset =utf-8',
          success: function (data) {
                   var obj = data.d;
                   if (obj == 'true')
                         alert("Data Saved Successfully");
                   },
                   error: function (result) {
                         alert("Error Occured, Try Again");
                   }
                });
           })
```

When I write it in html file it works properly
but when I put it in another .js file it doesn't work
here is head of my html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

and i put this inside of my body

```
 <script src="gh.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You need to wrap the JS code that you put in the `gh.js` file within a document.ready event handler

Comment: Also note that jQuery 1.8.2 is a little outdated now. I'd suggest upgrading to at least 1.12 if you need IE support. 3.x if you don't.

Comment: it works inside html with no problem. why not work in another .js?

Comment: It all depends on where you put the script. If it's in the head you need to add document.ready. Also note that you should remove `async: false` as it's terrible practice. The browser will be giving you warnings about its use if you check the console